# How to access data in a Component from HTML markup (Angular 4)

Tags: angular, typescript, datagrid, angular-pipe

I am trying to implement a datagrid for use in Angular 4. I don't really want to reinvent the wheel but it appears commercial ones are very expensive and the free ones I have found have very limited functionality.

In the HTML I iterate over the data items by:

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of ViewData">
```

and then iterate over the columns by:

```
<ng-template ngFor let-col [ngForOf]="Columns">
```

and each item is displayed by:

```
<td >{{item[col.property]}}</td>
```

The `Columns` is an array of Objects that describe each column such as:

```
{ heading: 'First Name', property: 'firstName', sortable: true }
```

This all works wonderfully - I retrieve the data from an API and present it to the grid and it is all properly displayed.

But not all fields in the DB are stored such that the default display is suitable. Dates are such a field. So in a column that contained a date of birth I modified the HTML to:

```
<td>{{item[col.property] | date:"MM-dd-yyyy"}}</td>
```

the date was displayed as required.

So I modified the column definition to:

```
{ heading: 'DOB', property: 'dob', sortable: true, pipe: 'date:"MM-dd-yyyy"' }
```

and changed the HTML to

```
<td *ngIf="col.pipe === undefined">{{item[col.property]}}</td>
<td *ngIf="col.pipe != undefined">{{item[col.property] | col.pipe}}</td>
```

but that doesn't work. My thinking was that the user could define the pipe but if not supplied the default presentation would be used. I think the fix to make that work must be really simple, but I can't see it. 
I have worked around it by:

```
{ heading: 'DOB', property: 'dob', sortable: true, pipeType: 'date', pipeParams: ["MM-dd-yyyy"] }
```

and changing the HTML to:

```
<td *ngIf="col.pipeType == 'date'">{{datePipe.transform(item[col.property], col.pipeParams[0])}}</td>
```

which works but it means I have to have a different `*ngIf` for every type of Pipe which would obviously be a maintenance nightmare. It would also make it far more difficult for users to supply their own custom pipes because they wouldn't have access to the HTML.

Any help much appreciated. Alternatively, if someone knows of a really good free or at least cheap fully functioning datagrid for Angular 4, that would work too.

Comment: Have you checked out the Angular Material Design data table? https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview